# Alter table transaction, create and manage table

Tags: mysql

Alter table transaction to make sure the transaction type should be either `Deposit` or `Withdrawal` and `transaction type` can not be kept empty

code:

```
alter transaction type buses
    add CUSTOMER varchar2(255);
```

how to add constraints

Comment: MySQL supports foreign keys, which let you cross-reference related data across tables - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: error in datatype check

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `check` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE transactions
ADD CONSTRAINT transactions_type_ck
CHECK (transaction_type IN ('Deposit', 'Withdrawal'));
```

Comment: The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See Section 1.8.2.3, “Foreign Key Differences”. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html Why do you think differently?

Comment: @P.Salmon TBH, I didn't even notice the tags. If the columns is really `varchar2`, OP is probably using [tag:oracle]